# Writing a string to NSPasteBoard

Tags: cocoa, xcode, pasteboard

I cannot get this method to return YES:

```
- (BOOL) writeToPasteBoard:(NSString *)stringToWrite
{
    return [pasteBoard setString:stringToWrite forType:NSStringPboardType];
}
```

I have verified that stringToWrite is coming through properly, the method just always returns NO.

Any ideas?

Here is the rest of the class:

```
@interface ClipBoard : NSObject {
    NSPasteboard *pasteBoard;
}

- (BOOL) writeToPasteBoard:(NSString *)stringToWrite;
- (NSString *) readFromPasteBoard;
@end

@implementation ClipBoard
- (id) init
{
    [super init];
    pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    return self;
}

- (BOOL) writeToPasteBoard:(NSString *)stringToWrite
{
    return [pasteBoard setString:stringToWrite forType:NSStringPboardType];
}

- (NSString *) readFromPasteBoard
{
    return [pasteBoard stringForType:NSStringPboardType];
}
```

@end

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is the working version of the method:

```
- (BOOL) writeToPasteBoard:(NSString *)stringToWrite
{
    [pasteBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
    return [pasteBoard setString:stringToWrite forType:NSStringPboardType];
}
```

Comment: You should use nil for object pointers, NULL only for non-object pointers. Using the wrong one misleads the reader (who will be you six months from now).

Comment: Actually this code snippet came from an Apple provided example. I think they would know the right way to do things.

But I digress, it is now changed to nil.

Comment: Sometimes Apple examples are written hastily or were written a long time ago. Some of the "Sample Code" projects they provide contain crimes against nature. Things change, stale examples are forever. :-)

Answer (score 21):

### Swift 2:

Copy a string to the general pasteboard with Swift 2:

```
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboardTypeString], owner: nil)
pasteboard.setString("Hello", forType: NSPasteboardTypeString)
```

Answer (score 21):

Before you copy a string on **NSPasteboard** it's better to clear the contents and then save.

**Swift 4**

```
    // Set string
    NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
    NSPasteboard.general.setString("I copied a string", forType: .string)
    // Read copied string
    NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string)
```

**Objective-C**

```
    // Set string
    [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] clearContents];
    [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:@"I copied a string" forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
    // Read string
    [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
```

And also there are other available types for copying items on **NSPasteboard**. Like:

- NSPasteboardTypeString
- NSPasteboardTypePDF
- NSPasteboardTypeTIFF
- NSPasteboardTypePNG
- NSPasteboardTypeRTF

You can find more details on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardtype.

Answer (score 16):

As of 10.6, the following implementation is also possible:

```
- (BOOL) writeToPasteBoard:(NSString *)stringToWrite
{
    [pasteBoard clearContents];
    return [pasteBoard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:stringToWrite]];
}
```

It's important to notice that #clearContents has to be called before something new can be written to the pasteboard, otherwise #writeObjects: keeps returning NO.

The new #writeObjects: methods is possible for objects that conform to the NSPasteboardWriting protocol. There's also an NSPasteboardReading Protocol, but using it wouldn't make the implementation any simpler.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the big gotcha: have to clear the clipboard before writing.

Answer (score 15):

Apple is suggesting people move away from NSStringPboardType and use NSPasteboardTypeString instead.

Comment: Agreed. But it's always better to write both types as legacy apps may not read the new one (NSPasteboardTypeString).

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 version:

```
NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
NSPasteboard.general.setString("Hello World", forType: .string)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

To copy a string in the clipboard you need to "prepare the pasteboard" before set string to copy

```
    NSPasteboard.general.prepareForNewContents()
    NSPasteboard.general.setString(stringToCopy, forType: .string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5,

```
let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteBoard.clearContents()
pasteBoard.setString("Test string",forType :.string)
```

Retrieve part,

```
NSTextField.pasteAsPlainText(NSPasteboard.general.string(forType:.string)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on Mojave 10.14.5 and does not use any deprecated APIs:

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSPasteboardTypeString, nil] owner:nil];
[pasteboard setString:@"Hello clipboard!" forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
```

Answer (score 1):

For macOS 10.12 and later:

```
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.prepareForNewContents()
pasteboard.writeObjects(["hello world" as NSString])
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, to copy a string to the system clipboard, you can use

```
NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
[pasteBoard setString:string forType:NSStringPboardType];
```