# Swift 3 copy string to clipboard

Tags: swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra, nspasteboard

How do you `Copy` a string to `Clipboard` in macOS 10.12 with Xcode 8 and Swift 3?
I am not able to find any reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34902953/3141234

Comment: you can see my comment in that answer, it does not work for Swift 3

Comment: So try to update it. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nspasteboard) would probably be handy. As is autocompletion.

Comment: Sorry, I only had to add import AppKit. What a stupid error!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Swift 3 you copy it like this way.

```
 let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general()
 pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboardTypeString], owner: nil)
 pasteboard.setString("Good Morning", forType: NSPasteboardTypeString)
```

Comment: This is not for macOS but iOS

Comment: Ok thank you, if you add import AppKit I will mark as best question

Comment: @LucaMarconato Edited answer for that.

Comment: I have tried and it does not work, after lunch I will try to fix it

Comment: @LucaMarconato Edited the answer, there is no need to import the `AppKit` I have try this code and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Working perfectly (I still have to add AppKit)

Comment: @LucaMarconato Welcome mate, I have tried this In Xcode 8 with Swift 3 and it is working without importing `AppKit` may be something else is missing.

Answer (score 34):

In Swift 5.2 (on macOS 10.15) the answer is slightly different:

```
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.declareTypes([.string], owner: nil)
pasteboard.setString("Good Morning", forType: .string)
```